# What is meant by Category theory doesn't yet know how to deal with higher-order functions?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

In reading [Uday Reddy's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/207/uday-reddy) [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9815/268) to [What is the relation between functors in SML and Category theory?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9769/268) Uday states

> Category theory doesn't yet know how to deal with higher-order
>   functions. Some day, it will.

As I thought Category theory was able to serve as a foundation for math, then it should be possible to derive all of math and higher-order functions.

So, what is meant by Category theory doesn't yet know how to deal with higher-order functions? Is it valid to consider Category theory as a foundation for math?

Comment: This discussion would be perfect for [cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue with higher-order functions is simple enough to state.

- A type-constructor like $T(X) = [X \to X]$ is not a functor.  It should have been.
- A polymorphic function like ${\it twice}_X : T(X) \to T(X) = \lambda f.\, f \circ f$ is not a natural transformation.  It should have been.

If you read [Eilenberg and MacLane's original category theory paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1990284), [(PDF)](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-058-00/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6.pdf) the intuitions they present cover those cases.  But their theory doesn't.  Theirs was a *great paper* for 1945!  But, today, we need more.

The reaction of category theorists to these issues is a bit perplexing.  They act as if higher-order operations form a Computer Science idea; they are of no consequence to mathematics.  If that is so, then a foundation of mathematics would not be good enough for a foundation of computer science.

But I don't seriously believe that.  I believe that higher-order functions would be quite important for mathematics as well.  But they have not been seriously explored.  I am hopeful that, some day, they will be explored and the limitations of category theory will be realized.

Comment: It's amazing that they don't consider higher-order functions interesting, considering the depths they go when exploring higher-dimensional algebra, n-category theory and the like. Comparatively, higher order functions seem so down-to-earth. Especially, if that earth involves Haskell programs.

Comment: @DaveClarke.  I think what they would like to see is a compelling example like the one Eilenberg and MacLane start with.  All $n$-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic to each other.  So, a vector space is isomorphic to its own dual: $A \cong A^*$.  However, these isomorphisms are not "natural". (They use particular bases - "representation-dependent" in our speak.)  On the other hand the isomorphism $A \cong A^{**}$ is "natural", works the same way for all bases.  To ask for a Category Theory 2.0, we need a similar killer example!

Comment: @DaveClarke. What happens in normal mathematics is that mathematicians very cleverly reduce higher-order things to first-order structures.  For instance, the type $T(X)$ I gave above is just a monoid, whose multiplication is a *first-order* operation.  If you recall your Linear Algebra, the linear transformations $A \to B$ are turned into a vector space, and then all its operations become first-order.  Automata theory (Computer Science again) might have been the first place where this trick did not work.  If Eilenberg had another 10 years of active life, he might have got on to the problem.

Comment: +1 This is really interesting. Do you know any reference that discusses these issues further?

Comment: You've caught my interest too.

Comment: @Kaveh:  There is plenty of literature on the subject.  But very few people would put things in such strong terms as I do, for fear of offending category theorists.  So, you have to read between the lines to see what they are really saying!

Comment: $T(X) = [X \to X]$ is a functor in a category of section-retraction pairs.

Comment: @UdayReddy  Arguably, there is a clever first-orderisation of higher-order functions, namely R. Milner's [Functions as processes](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/54/05/PDF/RR-1154.pdf), which
translates $\lambda$-calculus into $\pi$-calculus. The game-theoretic first-orderisations of functions are variants of Milner's idea. Of course $\pi$-calculus is not itself playing nicely with current, category theoretic notions of homomorphism. So today, when we compare processes, we generally use variants of bisimulations as tools. Maybe that's no coincidence?

Comment: I thought mathematics treated higher-order functions under the name of [functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28mathematics%29). In statistics, I encountered [Gâteaux derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative).

Comment: @Raphael.  Indeed, there are plenty of places where higher-order functions pop up in mathematics.  It will be great if any of them can lead to an example of a *useful* higher-order polymorphic function, which fails to be "natural" by the Eilenberg-MacLane definition.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: There is indeed some connection between "algebraically compact" categories and parametricity, which slips my mind now.  But I would hold that the problems of mixed variance are more general, which should be dealt with even before we consider diverging elements.

Comment: @MartinBerger: Indeed, the apparent "first-orderness" of $\pi$-calculus is thus deceptive.   The same kind of issues arise in dealing with simple imperative programs and finite state automata as well, as I mention in my second answer.

Comment: @UdayReddy I don't understand your answer. What makes $\pi$-calculus non first-order?

Comment: The section-retraction pairs are not just about algebraic compactness or divergence. They also take care of mixed variance by having morphisms which "go in both directions". And I never said "algebraically compact", actually.

Comment: @AndrejBauer. Ok, fair enough.  Do these categories with section-retraction pairs allow one to treat, for instance, ${\it twice}_X$ as a natural transformation?

Comment: @MartinBerger.  I wish I knew.  You are the $\pi$-calculus expert!  My feeling is that whenever we deal with state, we have state transformation functions whose type is like $T(X)$ -- where $X$ represents the state set.  So, dealing with state is inherently higher-order.

Comment: @UdayReddy I'm not sure. Depends what you mean by higher-order. State transformation functions are one specific way of understanding stateful languages, but surely not the only one.

Comment: @MartinBerger. "Higher-order" has the effect that the type $T(X)$ has both *covariant* and *contra-variant* occurrences of $X$.  My feeling is that that kind of mixed variance remains no matter what formalism you use to represent the phenomena.  That is my explanation in any case.  If the present theory of $\pi$-calculus is unable to explain why homomorphisms are not enough to compare processes, then it seems that that is a question for the $\pi$-calculus experts to think about!

Comment: @UdayReddy There isn't just one translation of $T(X) = X \rightarrow X$, e.g. CBV, CBN, ... If you look at the standard CBV translation, you get $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)^{\bullet} =((\overline{\alpha^{\bullet}}(\beta^{\bullet})^{\uparrow})^{!})^{\uparrow}$ where $\overline{\alpha^{\bullet}}$ is the dualisation of the translation $\alpha^{\bullet}$. Dualisation simply means exchanging input for output and vice versa.  So yes, you keep mixed variance. I don't know if homomorphisms are enough, because there is no good notion of homomorphism in the sense of categories in process theory.

Comment: @UdayReddy I believe that this is because categorical composition is too restricted to give a good account of process composition. However, if we restrict our attention to very specific processes such as
the translation of e.g. typed $\lambda$-calculi, it might be possible
to investigate what generalisation of the concepts of functor and natural transformation are required, so that type constructors like
$((\overline{\alpha^{\bullet}}(\beta^{\bullet})^{\uparrow})^{!})^{\uparrow}$ have nice, abstract properties. It's an interesting question.

Comment: @MartinBerger.  Sorry, I didn't mean that you need to encode $T(X)$ in anything.  My meaning was that a type such as $T(X)$ is involved in the guts of of any state-manipulating mechanism, including the $\pi$-calculus.  That is likely to be the reason why you need bisimulation relations rather than homomorphisms to compare processes.  (This issue is not resolved by encoding something in $\pi$-calculus.)

Comment: @UdayReddy That may well be the case, but doesn't it show that the issue is not higher-orderness, since the $\pi$-calculus isn't, but rather something else?

Comment: Yes, from your point of view, the issue is mixed variance.

Comment: @UdayReddy Something just occurred to me, but it's far from well-though out: although Milner, and many following his lead, have translated higher-order functions into calculi like $\pi$ that are, prima facie, first order, Milner's encoding is really 'just' an encoding up to strong  bisimulation (IIRC). It might be the case, but this would have to be checked more thoroughly, that higher-orderness sneaks back in through this quotienting.

Comment: @MartinBerger. As I said previously, I believe that $\pi$ calculus is "higher-order" on its own.  No need to encode anything.  Humble finite automata are already "higher-order".  See the paper on "Products of Automata" that I mentioned in my second answer, written way back in 1963!  Basic imperative programs are "higher-order".  That is what Milner's 1968 paper shows.  Apparently, you can't do anything stateful without being higher-order.  Quite amazing!

Comment: @UdayReddy I know you've been saying this. What I'm trying to find out is if it's true! ;-) To  do this, it would be helpful to formalise the notions first/higher-order at play here.

Answer (score 10):

[This second answer presents an outline of what a "Category Theory 2.0", that deals with higher-order functions properly, might look like.]

We have known for a long time how to deal with higher-order functions in reasoning about them.

- When an algebraic structure has higher-order operations, homomorphisms don't work.  We must use *logical relations* instead.  In other words, we must move from "*functions* preserving structure" to "*relations* preserving structure".
- To talk about "uniform" or "simultaneously given" transformations on higher-order types, naturality doesn't work.  We must use *relational parametricity* instead.  In other words, we must move from "families preserving all *morphisms*" to "families preserving all *logical relations*".
- Composition of logical relations is of no consequence.  The $\to$ type constructor doesn't preserve their composition, and nothing depends on it.  (This observation is at logger heads with the category theorists' belief that composition is fundamental!)

A quick introduction to these issues is in Peter O'Hearn's section on "Relational Parametricity" in [Domains and Denotational Semantics: History, Accomplishments and Open Problems](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/tenyears.ps.gz) [(CiteSeerX)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.3192).

- The first attempt at building a "Category Theory 2.0" is in O'Hearn and Tennent's [Parametricity and Local Variables](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=210425) [(CiteSeerX)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.6655).
- Brian Dunphy's PhD Thesis: [Parametricity as a notion of uniformity in reflexive graphs](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/papers/Brian-thesis.ps) [(CiteSeerX)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.988) builds on their framework and axiomatizes the relational structure needed to get parametricity results.  I would recommend Dunphy's thesis for getting a good overview of all the issues.
- For the sake of completeness, I should also mention Claudio Hermida's PhD thesis: [Fibrations, Logical Predicates and Indeterminates](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/daimipb/article/view/6935) [(PDF)](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/daimipb/article/download/6935/5898), which was the first to study logical relations in a category theoretic setting, but his treatment is perhaps too technical for most people.

I might also add that reasoning about *state* is where higher-order functions show up prominently.  Automata-theorists were the first to recognize that homomorphisms don't work correctly, in a historic paper called [Products of Automata and the Problem of Covering](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-116-00/S0002-9947-1965-0201228-X/S0002-9947-1965-0201228-X.pdf).  They used terms like "weak homomorphisms" and "covering relations" to refer to logical relations.  In due course, terms like "simulation" and "bisimulation" were used to refer to them.  Davide Sangiorgi's survey article: [On the Origins of Bisimulation and Coinduction](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~sangio/DOC_public/history_bis_coind.pdf) covers all of this early history and more.

The need for relational reasoning repeatedly crops up in reasoning about state, in particular *imperative programming*.  Very few people notice that the humble "semicolon" is a higher-order operation.  So, you cannot get off the ground in thinking about imperative programs without knowing how to deal with higher-order functions.  We keep ignoring the issues of state and imperative programming in the mistaken belief that mathematics has all the answers.  So, if mathematicians don't understand state, it must be no good!  Nothing could be further from the truth.  State is at the heart of Computer Science.  We will be advancing science in general by showing people how to deal with state!

Comment: @GuyCoder, I think that is good idea. By the way, I think this and that question would be on-topic also for [cstheory.se] in case you would prefer to post it there.

Comment: After dicussing with Uday, a new question will not be specifically asked for this second answer. :)

Comment: State is relativistic.